# What's the purpose of "Verify a User" in "Sign in with Apple"?

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

In [Sign in with Apple REST API | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi), there are two articles, [Authenticating Users with Sign in with Apple | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple) and [Verifying a User | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/verifying_a_user).

I can get the user identifier in "Authenticating Users with Sign in with Apple", but I'm having trouble understanding why "Verify the Identity Token" is needed giving that we have already got the user identifier. What's the purpose of "Verify the Identity Token"? And what's the purpose of "Obtain a Refresh Token"? What can we do using the refresh token and access token?

I can't find my answer in "Apple Developer Documentation".

Answer (score 1):

The user identity token that you get from sign-in with Apple is only valid for 10 minutes, because it could be intercepted and used in a replay attack.  It could also, conceivably, be forged.

You submit the user token to the verification endpoint in order to verify that it is a valid identity token that was issued by Apple.

You may also need some set of credentials in your server to allow it to issue access tokens; think "username and password", however in the case of Sign in With Apple you don't have a password; That is the role of the refresh token.

You can store the user's identifier and the refresh token in your server in lieu of an encrypted password and also store this in your app's keychain, for example.  Then the app can present the user identifier and the refresh token to your server in order to obtain an access token.

On iOS you can use `getCredentialState(forUserID:completion:)` to verify that the user is still valid.  On other systems you can periodically (once per day maximum) validate the refresh token to ensure that the user account is still in good standing with Apple.

Comment: So for a custom REST API -- are you suggesting to send the user identifier and refresh token from client to server?

Comment: "validate the refresh token' is equivalent to 'issue new access token'? what does the `getCredentialState` function check?

Comment: No, you never get a new access token.  The refresh token is akin to a password; you can store it indefinitely.  Once per day you can verify that it is still valid (ie. the user behind it still exists) [getCredentialState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidprovider/3175423-getcredentialstate) - It is an inexpensive on-device call (so it doesn't hit the network) to tell you whether the user id is still valid or not.